# How can I respawn at a specific location after dying?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Whenever I respawn, I will either spawn into my map, or outside. This happens everytime, even when I set the worldspawn to the correct location.

Am I supposed to use the sort of contraption where you can play a title when you die, but instead use it to teleport when they are dead?

[image: What can I do to stop spawning outside of the map? Here's a picture of it.]

I'll be very thankful if you could tell me anything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Players spawn at a random location in a certain radius around the world spawn. By restricting this radius to 0 blocks, you can force them to spawn at the block you selected:

```
/gamerule spawnRadius 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this gamerule existed until now. You learn something new everyday!